# How can I sort id and sub_id in descending order?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table is like ...

```
id  Sub_id  name    path    date

1   33  Sanjay  Something here to all   Some thing
2   33  Sanjay      
3   34  Fariya      
4   35  Neeraj      
5   35  Neeraj      
6   32  Mukesh      
7   37  Ravi        
8   32  Mukesh      
9   32  Mukesh      
10  32  Mukesh
```

When I use this query - where table name is gallery...

`$sql="select * from (select * from gallery order by id  desc 4)  gallery  group  by Sub_id desc limit 4";`

I need it in this format

```
id  Sub_id  name    path    date
10  32  Mukesh  Something here to all   Some thing
7   37  Ravi        
5   35  Neeraj      
3   34  Fariya
```

Please, help me...

Comment: Please edit your question in proper format.

Comment: @Dr.Dan You could have helped out a new user as well mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id), 
    Sub_id, 
    name, 
    path, 
    date 
FROM 
    gallery 
GROUP BY 
    Sub_id
ORDER BY 
    id DESC 
LIMIT 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

With your original SQL as base (if you want to sort first for id and then for sub_id):

```
$sql="select * from gallery group by sub_id order by id desc, subid desc limit 0,4";
```

If it is not intended to eliminate the "duplicates", then the following sql could be used instead of the above one:

```
$sql="select * from gallery order by id desc, subid desc limit 0,4";
```

Answer (score 0):

please  try this

```
select * from  (select max(id), sub_id from gallery group by sub_id order by id desc) where rownum <=4;
```