# How can i do sort id and sub_id in descending order in php

Tags: php, sql, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sort id and sub_id in descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718434/how-can-i-sort-id-and-sub-id-in-descending-order)

I have a mysql table named `gallery` .

```
id    sub_id    name
1       10      jack
2       10      jack
3       11      rom
4       11      rom
5       12       win
6       12       win
7       13      shivam
8       13      shivam
```

There are 4 different sub_id but all have different id. So i just want to fetch only one id from every sub_id in descending order like below :

```
id     sub_id      name
8        13        shivam
6        12        win
4        11         rom
2        10        jack
```

I used this query but it doesn't help me .

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(id), sub_id, name FROM gallery GROUP BY sub_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

Comment: You just asked this a few minutes ago?

Comment: The query you gave is not at all related to the table you have shown

Comment: i don't think so that you can short both id, and sub_id in the same time. The sort order works only work with the first applied field. Make me correct if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you may try by the following query

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(id), sub_id, sub_name FROM gallery GROUP BY sub_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

Comment: thank u but it does not work properly....

Answer (score 0):

You should select the max "sub_id" of every group to obtain the desired result, and if the "id" is already ordered you needn't to put an order statement. So the query must look like this:

```
SELECT MAX(  `id` ) ,  `sub_id` ,  `name` 
FROM  `gallary` 
GROUP BY  `sub_id`
```

for the limit you can add it easily. I hope that it helps.